# Laravel 5.2 - Form do not submit

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Sorry, i'm very new to Laravel, i have this form:

```
<form action="/register" method="post">
   {!! csrf_field() !!}     
   ....         
<div class="form-group">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
</div>
</form>
```

And the route is:

```
Route::get('/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

When i click on `Register` button nothing happen... the form do not submit, no errors etc.

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 3):

Change this

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
```

to

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
```

and always use dynamic url so that when you deploy your app to server,then you get no error(s)

```
action="{{ url('/register') }}
```

Comment: Or even better...name the route i.e. `route('register');` `Route::post('register', ['as' => 'register', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister']);`

Comment: @Mistre83 no prob bro we are glad to help you!

Answer (score 1):

Change the type of the button:

```
<button type="submit"
```